# Триггер mySql в phpMyAdmin на проверку одинаковых знаний

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Есть две таблицы: основная таблица (products) и таблица с историей изменений основной таблицы (change_history).

1. Основная таблица имеет следующие столбцы:
   | Id | Name | Place | Price |
2. и таблица с историей изменений основной таблицы:
   | Id | product_id | product_name | product_place | product_price | date |

Необходимо, чтобы при добавлении нового продукта или изменении уже существующего, строчка с изменённым продуктом добавлялась в таблицу с историей изменений. Для этого я сделал триггер.
Но проблема в том, что в основном меняется только цена продукта, а остальные поля меняются редко и из-за этого в таблицу с историей добавляется много повторяющихся значений названия продукта, которое меняется редко. Я подумал о том, чтобы модифицировать триггер и перед тем, как добавлять новую строчку в таблицу с историей проверять существуют ли значения из этой строчки в соответствующих столбцах и если да, то обнулять их.
Я написал триггер, но почему то он не работает:

```
TRIGGER `new_change` AFTER UPDATE ON `products`

BEGIN

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT product_name FROM change_history WHERE product_name = NEW.name) THEN
    BEGIN
    INSERT INTO change_history(product_name,) VALUES (NEW.name);
    END;
END IF;
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT product_place,  FROM change_history WHERE product_place,  = NEW.place) THEN
    BEGIN
    INSERT INTO change_history(product_place) VALUES (NEW.place);
    END;
END IF;
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT product_price,  FROM change_history WHERE product_price,  = NEW.price) THEN
    BEGIN
    INSERT INTO change_history(product_price) VALUES (NEW.price);
    END;
END IF;

END
```

Подскажите, в чем может быть проблема и как может быть лучше реализовать данный функционал?

Comment: *Основная таблица имеет следующие столбцы* Ниачём. Выложите соответствующие CREATE TABLE. *перед тем, как добавлять новую строчку в таблицу с историей проверять существуют ли значения из этой строчки в соответствующих столбцах и если да, то обнулять их.* Совершенно непонятно... покажите примером. *Я написал триггер, но почему то он не работает* Триггер не может "не работать". Он либо не даёт ожидаемого результата, либо вызывает ошибку.

Comment: Ссылки на картинки с примерами: как выглядит таблица истории с повторяющимися значениями и таблица, которую я хочу добиться 
     https://ibb.co/KsNvBWC
https://ibb.co/QkWWnG5

Comment: @Сергей во-первых, это не CREATE TABLE, во-вторых, тексты должны быть текстами, а не картинками, а в-третьих, эти тексты должны быть в тексте вопроса, а не в комментариях (и уж точно не ссылками на сторонние сайты)

Comment: Текст Я уже в вопросе написал. А сейчас я захотел показать наглядный пример в виде картинки для тех кто захочет помочь. В каком виде мне это делать и какие ссылки отправлять Я разберусь без ваших советов.

Comment: @Сергей это не "советы", а правила сайта, при несоблюдении которых вопрос может быть закрыт и/или удалён

Comment: Если кто не дружит со здравым смыслом пускай удаляет